# Where does this question actually belong?

Tags: discussion

It seems hard to place this question on Stackoverflow to correct site:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/8301303/75642

Reading comments people would place it on:

- server fault
- programmers
- dba

and maybe even

- superuser

I'm pretty sure it doesn't belong to stackoverflow. I voted for programmers. But where would it actually fit best?

> **important**: This question got transferred to http://dba.stacexchange.com which atually seems to be the best option (although not available to close-rep moderators within the options that open).

Comment: +1 for coming here to ask instead of continuing to wander around the site "blind"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmers SE is for non-programming matters that are unique to the programming profession (i.e. "being a programmer," not "doing programming"). This question is about databases. I think a comment posted to the question sums it up best:

> This is right up the alley of what DBAs do day-in-day-out. Database Administrators SE is chock full of extremely talented and experienced DBAs. They know the inner workings of the database engine like the back of their hands. – Shark 53 secs ago

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree although I close-voted for programmers because **(A)** there's no option for dba.se and **(B)** it seemed non-development question that is related to developers who decide on DB strategy... But yes DBA seems a much better fit.

Comment: Yeah, the lack of migration options can be annoying. You can always flag for a mod and say which site you think is right for migration; mods can migrate from anywhere to anywhere.